# Unable to debug in rubymine with rspec

Tags: rubymine

When running rubymine `debug` getting `Test framework quit unexpectedly error`.

```
Testing started at 11:41 AM ...
/bin/bash -c "env RBENV_VERSION=2.7.0 /home/workstation/.rbenv/libexec/rbenv exec bundle exec ruby /home/workstation/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.8.0.beta19/bin/rdebug-ide --key-value --step-over-in-blocks --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --evaluation-control --time-limit 100 --memory-limit 0 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 41145 --host 0.0.0.0 --dispatcher-port 37297 -- /home/workstation/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin/rspec /home/workstation/workspace/railsprojects/labx/spec/requests/api/v1/sellers_request_spec.rb --require teamcity/spec/runner/formatter/teamcity/formatter --format 'Spec::Runner::Formatter::TeamcityFormatter' --example 'Api::V1::Sellers POST register'"
/home/workstation/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/debase-0.3.0.beta19/lib/debase.rb:7:in `require': cannot load such file -- debase_internals (LoadError)
    from /home/workstation/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/debase-0.3.0.beta19/lib/debase.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/workstation/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.8.0.beta19/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:9:in `require'
    from /home/workstation/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.8.0.beta19/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/workstation/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.8.0.beta19/bin/rdebug-ide:8:in `require_relative'
    from /home/workstation/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.8.0.beta19/bin/rdebug-ide:8:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Versions

> ruby: 2.7.0, rspec-rails:  4.0.0.pre, rails: 6-0-stable, Rubymine
>   2019.3.1

Only debug is failing if I run tests normally without debug it works fine. What could be the issue?

Comment: Does it work with another Ruby versions in the last 2019.3.2 Preview?

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced something similar when trying to use rubymine to debug rspec: `cannot load such file -- debase`

- Using rbenv
- On MacOS (I updated to the latest MacOS / XCode versions as part of this - though I am not sure that is necessary)

It seems that as of writing, rubymine ships with a custom version of debase that is different from what is available in github. I had to install the gem (The version may be different by the time anybody reads this):

```
gem install --local /Applications/RubyMine.app/Contents/plugins/ruby/rb/gems/debase-3.0.0.beta.8.gem
```

Then I had to add it to my Gemfile:

```
gem 'debase', '3.0.0.beta.8'
```

Side note: I added this to the list of files git assumes to be unchanged so I wasn't constantly accidentally committing it. This is annoying, but IMHO not being able to debug specs is more annoying. The Gemfile doesn't change that often for the project I am working on.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged Gemfile
git update-index --assume-unchanged Gemfile.lock
```

After a `bundle install` I was able to debug tests with rspec.